# What is the effect of surfactant deficiency on dead space (of lung volumes)?

Tags: respiration, lungs

Surfactant deficiency in adults with acute respiratory distress syndrome has long been recognized. This deficiency causes decrease in lung volumes (tidal volume or redisual volume for example).

Dead space is the portion of each tidal volume that does not take part in gas exchange.
So this deficiency cannot cause decrease in the volume of dead space, right?

I am asking this question because our teacher told us that this deficiency causes decrease in all lung volumes, without exception.